# Arranging the lines in required order

Tags: awk, sed, grep, sort, cut

A file contains lines as follows:

```
acb/xyz/row<t>
acb/xyz/row<t>
abc/xyz/row<1>
abc/xyz/row<1>
abc/xyz/row<0>
abc/xyz/row<0>
abc/xyz/row<3>
abc/xyz/row<3>
abc/xyz/row<2>
abc/xyz/row<2>
abc/xyz/row<4>
abc/xyz/row<4>
abc/xyz/row<b>
abc/xyz/row<b>
```

So I want the output to be

```
acb/xyz/row<t>
acb/xyz/row<t>
abc/xyz/row<b>
abc/xyz/row<b>
abc/xyz/row<0>
abc/xyz/row<0>
abc/xyz/row<1>
abc/xyz/row<1>
abc/xyz/row<2>
abc/xyz/row<2>
abc/xyz/row<3>
abc/xyz/row<3>
abc/xyz/row<4>
abc/xyz/row<4>
```

With t (for top) and b (for bottom) sorting before the numbers and in that order.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a decorate-sort-undecorate approach where you assign -2 to `t`, `-1` to `b` with:

```bash
<your-file awk -F'[<>]' '
  {print $2 == "t" ? -2 : $2 == "b" ? -1 : $2, $0}' |
  sort -n |
  cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Comment: More of a preference than anything else I suppose and obviously nbd at all, but if you add `-v OFS='\t'` to the awk command then you don't need `-d' '` in the `cut` command and in my mind at least it's aesthetically better to create the awk script in a way that accommodates the subsequent commands defaults rather than having to additionally tweak the subsequent commands to accommodate how the awk script is written.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways, but the best way I can think to do this involves using multiple commands, which you can do with a small script.

The script here first gets all lines with `<t>`, then gets all lines with `<b>`, then gets all lines with numerals inside `<#>` and sorts them numerically:

You can probably leave out the `| sort` in the first two commands if *only* what's inside the `<...>` matters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# get all rows with <t>
grep '<t>' input.txt | sort > output.txt

# get all rows with <b>, append to result
grep '<b>' input.txt | sort >> output.txt

# find lines with numbers inside <#>, pull the
# number out to start, sort numerically, then remove
# numbers pulled out to start; append to result
sed -n 's/.*<\([0-9]\+\)>.*/\1 &/p' input.txt | \
    sort -n | sed 's/^[0-9]\+ //' >> output.txt
```

I'm assuming the input file is `input.txt` and the output is `output.txt`; change as needed.

Make the script executable `chmod a+x script.sh` and run it `./script.sh`.

Comment: Note that there's nothing `bash` specific in that code so you could change the shebang to `#! /bin/sh -` and remove the bash dependency. The `\+` is specific to GNU `sed` though. The standard equivalent is `\{1,\}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I want a little more help. I have changed the question and I want a line with the given title at the starting of each new row number.

Comment: Are `<1>` through `<4>` the only numbers, or could there be an arbitrarily many numbers? Please don't get in the habit of changing questions; with the additional requirements, this becomes closer and closer to "hey, do free work for me" instead of "I have a particular question I need help with". The former is not what this site is for.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I am sorry about that. Numbers range from 0-30. This is my first time using stack exchange and also I am learning unix from past 1 week only, still understanding how things work, so I thought question should be one step at a time, after it is sorted then I need to add a heading (title) as shown in the question. I hope you don't mistake me. I will take care about this in future.